# How can I use the transaction backstack to pop fragments?

Tags: java, android, fragment, fragment-backstack

Suppose I have a MainActivity with FragmentContainerView.
This FragmentContainerView's size matches the MainActivity.

Then I want to show one fragment at a time in this FragmentContainerView.

Fragment1, Fragment2, and Fragment3.

Each fragment will have one button. When button is pressed, next fragment is loaded.

Fragment1 (Press button)--> Fragment2  (Press button)--> Fragment3 (Press button)--> Fragment1 --> and so on.

So far, I was able to implement, but I am not sure how to make my fragments such that, when I press the back button,

Fragment1 should exit app

Fragment2 should load Fragment1

Fragment3 should load Fragment2

Here is my **MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("CLASS_NAME", " ");
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container_view, fragment, null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Here is my **Fragment1**

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

       
        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.bind(getView());


        String previous_class = getArguments().getString("CLASS_NAME");
        if(!previous_class.equals(" ")){
            binding.textViewFirstFragment.setText(previous_class);
        }

        //On button click, navigate to MainActivity
        binding.buttonFirstFragment.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Log.i("BACKSTACK", "debug: current status of fragment back stack " + getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
        Fragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
        putBundleArgument(fragment);
        replaceFragment(fragment);
        debug();
    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_view, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Here is my **Fragment2**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

   
    binding = FragmentSecondBinding.bind(getView());

    String previous_class = getArguments().getString("CLASS_NAME");
    binding.textViewSecondFragment.setText(previous_class);
    //On button click, navigate to MainActivity
    binding.buttonSecondFragment.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Log.i("BACKSTACK", "debug: current status of fragment back stack " + getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
    Fragment fragment = new ThirdFragment();
    putBundleArgument(fragment);
    replaceFragment(fragment);
    debug();
}

public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_view, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Lastly, here is my **Fragment3**

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    
    binding = FragmentThirdBinding.bind(getView());

    String previous_class = getArguments().getString("CLASS_NAME");
    binding.textViewThirdFragment.setText(previous_class);
    //On button click, navigate to MainActivity
    binding.buttonThirdFragment.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Fragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
    putBundleArgument(fragment);
    replaceFragment(fragment);
    debug();

}
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    /*
    ThirdFragment fragment3 = new ThirdFragment();
    transaction.remove(fragment3);
    SecondFragment fragment2 = new SecondFragment();
    transaction.remove(fragment2);
    */
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();


    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_view, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

Comment: So which step in your code is going wrong? Is it when you are on FragmentOne the first time? After going to FragmentTwo and attempt to go back to One? After going to FragmentThree and going back to Two? Or after going back to One? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override // override this in MainActivity
 public void onBackPressed(){
     int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
     if(count == 1)//When there is only 1 fragment left in the stack ie Fragment 1.
        finsh();
     else
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); //Fragment 2 and 3 are popped here.
     super.onBackPressed();  
 }
```

Comment: This is what Fragments already do for you when you use `addToBackStack()`. Doing this manually is absolutely, 100% the wrong thing to do and fails to handle nested fragments and [custom back handling](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back).

Comment: @ianhanniballake I 100% agree this will lead to future problems, but this solution stems from their existing code base. Any time I've offered a solution that doesn't fix the problem, but leads to a design that inherently doesn't have it I get down voted. And by the looks of it, it worked for the asker. My original answer that I didn't post completely did away with the chaining fragment creation, which would lead to a more maintainable control structure.

Comment: I think this doesn't work anyways - when at FragmentThree, this will both pop the back stack (taking you to Two) and call `super.onBackPressed()` which will also pop the fragment back stack (taking you to One), which is not what you want.